# How to write unit/integration tests in ServiceStack

Tags: unit-testing, servicestack

I'm very new to ServiceStack. So far, I've had good fortune in getting a basic API up and working (the Northwind example was particularly helpful for me). However, I'm stumbling when trying to build unit and integration tests.

I've found a recent gist from another ServiceStack user who illustrated a few (possibly incorrect) examples of unit and integration tests, but I cannot get those working.

Here is the reference I've been using:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/435

Here is my attempt at a basic unit test, using mostly borrowed code from the other user's gist:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4957788

When I attempt to run the test case in HelloWorldTest, a System.NotImplementedException is thrown, stating "Unable to resolve service 'HelloWorldName'".

This is confusing to me, as I'm passing it a request DTO, not a service, which seems to agree with the ExecuteService() method I'm calling.  But the exception suggests that ServiceStack is treating my DTO as a service.

Could somebody possibly send me to a good, canonical example of how to correctly write unit and integration tests for ServiceStack?  I should mention that I'm also new to .NET development in general, so perhaps my ignorance is shining through.

Many thanks.

Comment: See this earlier [answer for an example of a Unit and Integration test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14791657/85785).

Comment: Thanks, mythz.  A question about integration tests.  With an end-to-end integration test, I need to have the service actually running in order to connect to it with a JsonServiceClient instance.

How do I go about that?

Comment: provided some links in answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [testing docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing) and [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790695/85785) and answer for a [simple example on how to create a Unit and Integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790695/unit-test-httprequest-headers-with-servicestack/14791657#14791657).

Also most of the tests in [ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests) are stand-alone integration tests that just use a self-hosted HttpListener AppHost. 
Some examples:

- [BufferedRequestTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/BufferedRequestTests.cs)
- [AuthTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AuthTests.cs)

Comment: So as I understand it, I can't use my existing AppHost when running integration tests, but instead I should be creating a new AppHost from AppHostHttpListenerBase. Does this mean I have to copy my existing Configure() method from my primary AppHost to this new AppHost in order to ensure all my DB/Redis connections are initialized correctly?

Comment: Well you can always run integration tests against a dev instance of own ASP.NET web application, but otherwise if you just want to test a subset of your service, yeah make a specific AppHost with just the things you wan to test. Otherwise stick to Unit testing services in isolation and just mock what you need.