# How do you mock ServiceStack ISession using Moq and StructureMap?

Tags: moq, structuremap, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack / StructureMap / Moq.  The service makes a call to Session, which is type ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ISession.  For unit tests, I created a Mock object using Moq, and added it to the StructureMap configuration:

```
protected Mock<ISession> sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
ObjectFactory.Configure(
    cfg =>
       {
           cfg.For<ISession>().Use(sessionMock.Object);
```

However, I was not surprised when the Session object was null -- I'm pretty sure I'm leaving out a step.  What else do I need to do to fill my Session property with a mock object?

[EDIT] Here's a simple test scenario

Code to test.  Simple request / service

```
[Route("getKey/{key}")]
public class MyRequest:IReturn<string>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class MyService:Service
{
    public string Get(MyRequest request)
    {
        return (string) Session[request.Key];
    }
}
```

The base test class and MockSession classes

```
// test base class
public abstract class MyTestBase : TestBase
{
    protected IRestClient Client { get; set; }

    protected override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        // this code is never reached under any of my scenarios below
        container.Adapter = new StructureMapContainerAdapter();
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(
            cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.For<ISession>().Singleton().Use<MockSession>();
                });
    }
}

public class MockSession : ISession
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        m_SessionStorage[key] = value;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)m_SessionStorage[key];
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return m_SessionStorage[key]; }
        set { m_SessionStorage[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

And tests. See comments for where I'm seeing the failure.  I didn't really expect versions 1 & 2 to work, but hoped version 3 would.

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_getting_a_session_value:MyTestBase
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_version_1()
    {
        var session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MockSession>();
        session["key1"] = "Test";
        var request = new MyRequest {Key = "key1"};
        var client = new MyService();  // generally works fine, except for things like Session
        var result = client.Get(request);  // throws NRE inside MyService
        result.ShouldEqual("Test");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_version_2()
    {
        var session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MockSession>();
        session["key1"] = "Test";
        var request = new MyRequest {Key = "key1"};
        var client = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyService>();
        var result = client.Get(request);  // throws NRE inside MyService
        result.ShouldEqual("Test");
    }
    [Test]
    public void Test_version_3()
    {
        var session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MockSession>();
        session["key1"] = "Test";
        var request = new MyRequest {Key = "key1"};
        var client = CreateNewRestClient();
        var result = client.Get(request);  // throws NotImplementedException here
        result.ShouldEqual("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's because I don't have the StructureMap adaptor configured properly, when unit testing.  Not sure how to do that...

Comment: Can you show all the code for the test? i.e. so we can see how you're calling the service?

Comment: Added code that shows the problem and how I tried to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create unit tests, but you're using an AppHost like you wound an Integration test. See this [previous answer for differences between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14791657/85785) and [docs on Testing](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing).

You can mock the Session by registering an instance in `Request.Items[Keywords.Session]`, e.g:

```cs
[Test]
public void Can_mock_IntegrationTest_Session_with_Request()
{
    using var appHost = new BasicAppHost(typeof(MyService).Assembly).Init();
    
    var req = new MockHttpRequest();
    req.Items[Keywords.Session] = new AuthUserSession {
        UserName = "Mocked"
    };

    using var service = HostContext.ResolveService<MyService>(req);
    Assert.That(service.GetSession().UserName, Is.EqualTo("Mocked"));              
}
```

Otherwise if you set `AppHost.TestMode=true` ServiceStack will return the `IAuthSession` that's registered in your IOC, e.g:

```cs
[Test]
public void Can_mock_UnitTest_Session_with_IOC()
{
    using var appHost = new BasicAppHost
    {
        TestMode = true,
        ConfigureContainer = container =>
        {
            container.Register<IAuthSession>(c => new AuthUserSession {
                UserName = "Mocked",
            });
        }
    }.Init();

    var service = new MyService {
        Request = new MockHttpRequest()
    };
    Assert.That(service.GetSession().UserName, Is.EqualTo("Mocked"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was so focused on thinking I *had* to create the service using one of the SS methods I didn't look into manually filling ISessionFactory.

Comment: np :) ServiceStack is pretty much binded together with simple clean classes and interfaces, so most of the time the easiest thing will work :)

Comment: Worked great, too! Changed it oonly a little to work with StructureMap.

Comment: @mythz I'm running into a Null Reference Exception in one of my tests (your comment on line 14 mentions it)... is there any way to get ahold of actual mocked session properties from _within_ the service?

Comment: I found this when looking to mock a session, and saw that you were going to look to simplify the effort required.  Did you ever look at this?  If so, is there a new strategy?  Thanks.

Comment: @TortillaCurtain see updated answer with how I would mock the Session now.